# How to replace old module .dll with new version in DirectoryModuleCatalog

Tags: wpf, prism

I am using DirectoryModuleCatalog to create the module catalog in my prism app. I have placed the module .dll files in a folder from where I pick the modules. Now say after some time one of the module's code gets updated and I need to install (place it) to my directory, then how to remove old version of it and place a new version there?

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        DirectoryModuleCatalog catalog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Modules") };
        return catalog;
    }
```

Comment: Stop the app, delete the old file, copy the new file, start the app... sounds too simple, do I miss anything?

Comment: suppose a client installs the prism application, the modules .dll files will be placed in some folder on clients machine. When a client want to install a new version of any module, he will run the the setup(.exe) that I give it to him which places that .dll to that specific folder location. How would I handle two .dll files with same name??

Comment: You cannot have two files with the same name in the same folder, one has to be deleted first/overwritten. The installer should check that the app is closed and then copy the new module dll, overwriting the old one.